# 301 redirect using query parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am working on a redirect problem. Input link would be like:

`http://domain1.com/xyz?targetPCUrl=http://domain2.com/test?q1=val`

i.e. one of the query param in the full link (say 1st) is a link itself (say 2nd).

Now I want to write a apache htaccess rewriterule to redirect all such calls to 2nd link. I have this until now:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^targetPCUrl=([/a-zA-Z_-]*)
```

What should be the RewriteRule with flags `[R=301,L]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} targetPCUrl=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```